# How to scp a hidden dot directory

Tags: shell, scp

I need to copy a hiddden dot directory from remote to local. I tried this:

```
scp ssh:/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/ /local/target
```

But this gives me an error `scp: /home/ubuntu/.gnupg: not a regular file`

Comment: `man scp | less -p '-r'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a directory, you need `-r` switch for `scp`. So the command would be something like:

```
scp -r ssh:/home/ubuntu/.gnupg/ /local/target
```